# Referring to an array in a subclass

Tags: java

So im writing a program to add and subtract Polynomials. The Polynomial is comes in as a String (example: 4x^7-2x^5+3x^2+78) and its split up into Terms (example 4x^7) and then the coefficient value is assigned to PolynomialArray[exponent].

This is part one of my assignment so I have an Interface that was given to me below:

```
public interface PolynomialInterface {
PolynomialInterface add(PolynomialInterface other);

// Effect: Adds value to owner of addPolynomial method.
// Postcondition: Return value = this + value.
PolynomialInterface subtract(PolynomialInterface other);

// Effect: Subtracts value from owner of addPolynomial method.
// Postcondition: Return value = this - value.
void readPolynomial();

// Postcondition: polynomial read.
String toString();
// Postcondition: polynomial converted to string.
}
```

Heres my code so far:

```
import java.lang.*;

public class ArrayWithExponentAsIndexPolynomial implements     PolynomialInterface {
Integer PolynomialArray[] = new Integer[1000];
CharSequence minus = "-";
CharSequence plusMinus = "+-";
boolean FirstElementPos = true;

public ArrayWithExponentAsIndexPolynomial(String input) {
    if (input.charAt(0) == '-') {
        input = input.substring(1);
        FirstElementPos = false;
    }
    String inputPolynomial = input.replaceAll("-", "+-");
    // input.replace(minus, plusMinus);
    System.out.println(inputPolynomial);
    String[] splitTerms = inputPolynomial.split("\\+");
    // int PolynomialArray[] = new int[100];

    for (int i = 0; i <= splitTerms.length - 1; i++) {
        System.out.println(splitTerms[i]);
    }
    String tempTemp = splitTerms[1];

    int coef;
    int exponent;
    String tempExp = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < splitTerms.length; i++) {

        String tempTerm = splitTerms[i];
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Term we are working with " + tempTerm);
        boolean tempPos = true;
        if (tempTerm.contains("-")) {
            tempTerm = tempTerm.substring(1);
            System.out.println("After removing negative from term: "
                    + tempTerm);
            tempPos = false;
        }
        int IndexOfexponent = tempTerm.indexOf('^');

        if (IndexOfexponent == -1) {
            exponent = 1;
            // FirstElementPos = true;
        } else {
            tempExp = tempTerm.substring(IndexOfexponent + 1);
            exponent = Integer.parseInt(tempExp);

        }
        System.out.println("The exp is " + exponent);
        // String tempTerm = splitTerms[i];
        System.out.println("The term rn is: " + tempTerm);
        String tempTermNoCarrot = tempTerm.replaceAll("\\^" + tempExp, "");
        String tempCoef = tempTermNoCarrot.replaceAll("x", "");
        // String tempCoef = tempTermNoX.replaceAll(tempExp, "");
        System.out.println("THe Coeff rn is: " + tempCoef);
        coef = Integer.parseInt(tempCoef);

        if (tempPos == false || FirstElementPos == false) {
            coef = (coef * -1);
        }

        System.out.println("After everything, Coef is:" + coef
                + " and exp is: " + exponent);
        PolynomialArray[exponent] = coef;

    }

}

public PolynomialInterface add(PolynomialInterface other) {
    String finalOutput=null;
    //Integer top = this.PolynomialArray[i];
    Integer Sum[] = new Integer[100];
    for (int i = 99; i >= 1; i--){
        Integer top = this.PolynomialArray[i];
        Integer bottom = other.PolynomialArray[i];
        Sum[i] = top + bottom;
    }





    String tempOutput = null;
    for (int i = 99; i >= 1; i--) {

        if (Sum[i] != null && Sum[i] != 0) {
            tempOutput += "+";
            int outputCoef = Sum[i];
            tempOutput += outputCoef;
            tempOutput += "x^";
            tempOutput += i;
        }
    }
    String RemoveNull = tempOutput;
    tempOutput = RemoveNull.replaceAll("null", "");
    if (tempOutput.charAt(0) == '+') {
        tempOutput = tempOutput.substring(1);
    }
    tempOutput = tempOutput.replaceAll("\\+-","-");
    finalOutput = tempOutput;




    return new ArrayWithExponentAsIndexPolynomial(finalOutput);



}

public PolynomialInterface subtract(PolynomialInterface other) {
    return other;
}

public void readPolynomial() {

}

public String toString() {
    String output = null;
    for (int i = 99; i >= 1; i--) {

        if (PolynomialArray[i] != null && PolynomialArray[i] != 0) {
            output += "+";
            int outputCoef = PolynomialArray[i];
            output += outputCoef;
            output += "x^";
            output += i;
        }
    }
    String outputTemp = output;
    output = outputTemp.replaceAll("null", "");
    if (output.charAt(0) == '+') {
        output = output.substring(1);
    }
    output = output.replaceAll("\\+-","-");
    return output;
}

}
```

My question is in the add mehthod, how do i refer to the PolynomialArray in the "other" object. When i do other.PolynomialArray[i] it says PolynomialArray cannot be resolved or is not a field sense in the Interface, there exists no such thing. Id there a way to refer to my intended target without changing the interface because in my future project I will need to use this

Sorry if I'm not being clear. This is my first time posting :)

*quick edit. I'm not done with my code so there are a few place holders here and there and some random print statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Integer PolynomialArray[] = new Integer[1000];`

This is something which your implementing Class `ArrayWithExponentAsIndexPolynomial` has added. It's not specified in your interface contract. You are trying to get the `PolynomialArray[]` from your interface reference. That won't work. You need to cast it like `((ArrayWithExponentAsIndexPolynomial)other).PolynomialArray[i];`

Comment: ahh perfect! this is exactly what i was missing. With a little bit of research, i understand perfectly now. THANKS!!!

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, the `PolynomialArray` field is defined in your `ArrayWithExponentAsIndexPolynomial` class and unknown to the given `PolynomialInterface` inferface. In practice, only methods are defined in an interface, not fields (as Amit.rk3 mentioned, static final fields are allowed, though no solution to your problem). A way to access a field of an object indentified solely by an interface, is to define a `getSomeField()` method in the interface.

I'm not sure if your assignment allows you to add `getPolynomialArray()` to the given interface, but that would be the simplest solution.

Otherwise, though less elegant, you can cast the given object to your class and access the field directly.

Comment: **In fact, only methods can be defined in an interface, not fields** - this isn't correct. Interfaces can have fields. It's just that they have to be `pubic static final`. Refer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446893/fields-in-interfaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446893/fields-in-interfaces).

Comment: @Amit.rk3 thank you, I didn't know that, I'll re-phrase my answer. Though I don't think I'll ever use it, and it's clearly of no help to the OP.