# Why interface has fields and they're public?

Tags: java

I understand those fields are `public static final` by default, my question is on why it's `public`?

I think my question comes from why interface has fields. Strangely I read from other answers on this site and accepted that they're `static final`, but why `public` is confusing for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fields in interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446893/fields-in-interfaces)

Comment: @jakub_d: I read that, still confused

Comment: an interface defines a contract, an API, sometimes you need specific constants to be used as part of that interface?

Comment: let's try to find some examples, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html <- these are all the constants in the standard library, at least some of those are in interfaces

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingConstants.html <- er, this one seems to be used to import convenient constants into multiple classes? eww

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Transparency.html <- this one appears somewhat sane

Comment: @jakub_d: Regard to your [constant-values-link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html), those are all interfaces?

Comment: not all of them, most are in regular classes, as I say "at least some are in interfaces"

Comment: @jakub_d: Can I say that interface should not involve what should be used in implementation, so its fields are public by default?

Comment: If we ignore the java 8 default methods feature, how would you use a non-public field in an interface anyway?

Comment: @jakub_d: I never think of it before... so private means it can only be used from inside?

Comment: @jakub_d: Maybe I need a reason about why not private instead of why it's public...

Comment: private can only be seen from the class itself and traditionally (before 8) interface methods had no implementation so no one would get to see the field

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192445/discussion-between-jakub-d-and-li-see-lei-cow-q-q).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relevant bit of spec:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3

> Every field declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly
>   public, static, and final. It is permitted to redundantly specify any
>   or all of these modifiers for such fields.

You are only allowed to redundantly affirm that you want public, trying to change it results in a compile-time error.

Private would be almost completely pointless (the implementing class would not be able to see the field).
If you say nothing you get public instead of the usual "package" visibility.
And you are prevented from specifying protected. Not sure if there is a valid use-case for wanting that.

Comment: Just a (and last) little question: now interface can have default methods, so it sounds like `private static final` fields of an interface can be used in them...?

Comment: @LiSeeLeiCow-Q__Q private fields in interfaces are still disallowed (see above), if they were allowed, they would be usable from a default method. And possibly through reflection. That's why I said *almost* completely pointless. :)

Comment: So the core of the answer is that the designers of the language made it so. You can come up with convoluted scenarios where it would make sense to have a non-public field, but the designers of the language wanted to encourage only this specific usage.

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces are meant to be implemented by other classes, not to encapsulate any data. This is why all fields are public.

Comment: Why interface needs fields?

Comment: I think my question comes from here, I can understand methods should be public.

Comment: Interfaces don't need fields.  The only reason to ever add fields to an interface is if you intend for them to be public.  Otherwise, just don't add them, and instead make them private fields in the implementing class.

Comment: I think this answer meant "methods", not "fields".