# What is the best practice (if al all) to implement an interface and have a common property?

Tags: java

What I actually ask, is if there is a way better than using an abstract class if I want all the implementations to have a common (but not static!) property.

For example:

```
public interface MyInterface{

   public int someProperty = 0;

   public void doSomething();

}

public ClassA implements MyInterface{

   @Override 
   public void doSomething(){...}
}

public ClassB implements MyInterface{

   @Override 
   public void doSomething(){...}
}
```

Is there a way to create instances of these two implementations and initialize someProperty member of the interface?

Or must I use abstract class instead of the interface in order to initialize this member per each implementing instance?

Comment: Java now allows default implementations for its interface members.  What prevents you from making the property `static`?

Comment: Don't define a common property like this. Use interfaces to define type only. Put the common property in a non-instantiable class.

Comment: @RobertHarvey that member *is* static (and final, and automatically public).

Comment: @AndyTurner: "Common but not `static`" feels like a contradiction in terms to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An interface in Java does not have member fields, only methods. (Discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9446893/642706).) In other words, an interface defines behavior, but not state.

You can imply a property exists by having JavaBeans-style accessor methods `get…` & `set…` declared on your interface.

If you want to ensure each object has its own member field of a certain type with a certain name, then yes, as you suggested, define an abstract class with that field.

Of course you can do both of these: write an abstract class holding the member field that implements the interface requiring the accessor methods. Whether doing both is a good idea or not depends on your specific scenario.

---

The following is one possible example scenario for having both (a) an abstract class carrying a member field, along with (b) an interface requiring getter/setter accessor methods. I am not entirely sure of the integrity of my logic in this example, but hopefully it conveys the general idea.

Vehicles come in all sorts. Some are legal to use on the public streets, and some are not. One aspect of being street-legal is having a [Vehicle identification number (VIN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_identification_number).

Let's define a hierarchy of vehicles.

- `Vehicle` is the grandparent superclass, and is abstract.
- `GoKart` is one child subclass of `Vehicle`, also abstract, and not legal to drive on streets.
- `Vin` is a record representing our Vehicle identification number (VIN) type.
- `Car` is another child subclass of `Vehicle`, also abstract. But a car is legal to drive on the street. This abstract class carries a `protected` class member of type `Vin`, inherited by any subclasses.
- To mark the `Car` class and its subclasses as being street legal, we define a `StreetLegal` interface. That interface defines a pair of methods to imply that a property `Vin` exists on all classes implementing this method.
- To pull this all together, we have one example concrete class [`HondaElement`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honda_Element) for a particular kind of car.

```java
package work.basil.example.cartalk;

public abstract class Vehicle
{
}
```

```java
package work.basil.example.cartalk;

// Not street-legal.
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go-kart
public abstract class GoKart extends Vehicle
{
    public boolean hasRemoteSpeedControl ;
}
```

```java
package work.basil.example.cartalk;

// VIN = Vehicle identification number.
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_identification_number#North_American_check_digits
public record Vin(String countryCode, int checkDigit, String serialNumber)
{
    // Add constructor to validate data.
}
```

```java
package work.basil.example.cartalk;

public abstract class Car extends Vehicle implements StreetLegal
{
    protected Vin vin ;
}
```

```java
package work.basil.example.cartalk;

public interface StreetLegal
{
    public Vin getVin ( );

    public void setVin ( Vin vin );
}
```

```java
package work.basil.example.cartalk;

public class HondaElement extends Car implements StreetLegal
{
    public HondaElement ( Vin vin )
    {
        this.vin = vin;   // Accessing member field defined on abstract superclass `Car`.
    }

    @Override
    public Vin getVin ( )
    {
        return this.vin;  // Accessing member field defined on abstract superclass `Car`.
    }

    @Override
    public void setVin ( Vin vin )
    {
        this.vin = vin;   // Accessing member field defined on abstract superclass `Car`.
    }
}
```

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash While I agree about the deteriorating situation on Stack Overflow, to be fair, this Question is not an appropriate example. As originally written there was some ambiguity about whether "common property` wording meant a single value shared across instances or a member field where each instance has its own value. Such ambiguity might justify a vote to close based on needing detail/clarity, though asking in a Comment could also be appropriate. Mark Rotteveel soon made an edit to clarify the Question; much improved now over its original condition.